# Execute particular rows from Excel and send to dataprovider.The 2D array is already taken care of by an existing method

Tags: excel, apache-poi, dataprovider, testng-dataprovider, testng-eclipse

I have 2D array in below format

[{1={name=as,execute=yes},2={name=sou,execute=no}]

These values are retrieved while reading values from Excel and are passed to dataprovider.

My need is to execute and pass only those rows where execute= yes.

I was trying to convert it into hashmap but wasnot getting desired result.please help

Can somebody help on how should I proceed

Comment: Without any code, it's a bit hard to see what you're doing wrong...

Comment: Actually the 2D array is given in the question.is it possible to parse so that I get the value of "execute" doing iteration? Based on iteration and execute = yes I want to take the entire row from the data provider